# AWS CLI - EC2 launch a shell script as user data

Tags: amazon-web-services, shell, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to launch a docker container, as job into an ec2 instance.

The EC2 instance is launched using the aws cli and UserData Shell Script encoded in base64:

```
$ aws ec2 run-instances --launch-template LaunchTemplateId=<TEMPLATE_ID>,Version=19 --key-name <KEY_NAME> --region <REGION> --user-data "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"
```

The base64 decoded script is the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Wait for specific service to be ready
while ! curl -sSf http://OTHER_AWS_IP:80/ping &> /dev/null; do
        echo "Waiting for HTTP server to be ready..."
        sleep 5
done
docker run --net smsnet -p 80:8090 -e UPLOAD_FOLDER=/app/upload/ -e PIPELINE_FOLDER=/app/pipeline/ -e spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://OTHER_AWS_IP:3306/ -e spring.datasource.username=DB_USER -e spring.datasource.password=DB_PASS -e spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver -e MYSQL_ADDR=OTHER_AWS_IP:3306 -e ENVIRONMENT_TYPE=AWS -e AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<AWS_ACCESS_KEY> -e AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=<AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY> -e AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=<AWS_DEFAULT_REGION> -e AWS_DEFAULT_TEMPLATE=<TEMPLATE_ID>,Version=19 -e AWS_LAN_SERVER_IP=<OTHER_AWS_IP> -e AWS_PUBLIC_SERVER_IP=<OTHER_AWS_IP> -e API_VERSION=V0.0.1 -e AWS_S3_BUCKET=<AWS_S3_BUCKETID> api:V0.0.1 java -jar /app/pipeline/lpp.jar /app/upload/1000040/1/config.txt
sudo poweroff -f now
```

The instance starts but the UserData Script is not launched.

Searching into the /var/log/cloud-init-output.log

> 2024-02-07 14:56:44,040 - **init**.py[WARNING]: Unhandled
> non-multipart (text/x-not-multipart) userdata:
> 'b'"IyEvYmluL2Jhc2gKIyBXYWl'...'

Instead if I use a simple script like:

```
echo "test" > /home/ec2-user/test.txt
```

I will find the test.txt

I also tried to decode the original script into the new instance and launch manually using

```
echo "BASE64encodedscripthere" | base64 --decode > script.sh
sh script.sh
```

The script is executed without any errors.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: run-instances performs the [base64 encoding for you](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html#user-data-api-cli).  If you place the script in a file, you can run it with something like `--user-data file://example.sh`, or you'll need to pass it in unencoded, with newlines, on the command line with something like `--user-data $'#!/bin/bash\necho example script'`